# How do I add NA values to create a data matrix from vectors of differing length?

Tags: r, na

I ran the apply function on a data frame in order to extract the positions of all cells with a value >-1.  However, in my results I have a different number of cells in each column and R will not allow me to convert the results into a data frame because of this.

Sample of my original data frame (Actual has 500+ columns):

```
Slopes<-data.frame(B1=5:495,B2=-100:390, B3=10:500,B4=-200:290)
row.names(Slopes)<-seq(0.01, 4.91, 0.01)
```

This is the function I ran over the vectors:

```
Z<-apply(Slopes, 2, function(x) which(x>-1))
```

How can I fill in the missing cells with "NA" so that I can convert these results into a data frame?

Also I just had to add this edit because now that I have successfully made the data frame, I have found that R returned the row numbers rather than the row names.  Any alterations I can make to my apply code which would return the row names instead?

Comment: Do you want to extract the value, or the position?

Comment: If you want to go from `Z` to a `data.frame`, just do `data.frame(lapply(Z, "length<-", max(lengths(Z))))`.

Comment: Why not use `which(Slopes > -1, arr.ind = TRUE)`  That will tell you exactly where the values are in Slopes

Comment: @AnandaMahto I tried your code and it worked well.  Like you asked, I am trying to extract their positions rather than their values.  However, it looks like my original apply code for this could have been better since it returned the row number.  What I actually need is the row name.  Any suggestions for this?

Comment: @user507, see the bottom of my answer for an approach to get the `rownames` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from your `Z`, you can use the following:

```
data.frame(lapply(Z, "length<-", max(lengths(Z))))
```

Output would be like:

```
> head(data.frame(lapply(Z, "length<-", max(lengths(Z)))))
     B1  B2 B3  B4
0.01  1 101  1 201
0.02  2 102  2 202
0.03  3 103  3 203
0.04  4 104  4 204
0.05  5 105  5 205
0.06  6 106  6 206
> tail(data.frame(lapply(Z, "length<-", max(lengths(Z)))))
      B1 B2  B3 B4
4.86 486 NA 486 NA
4.87 487 NA 487 NA
4.88 488 NA 488 NA
4.89 489 NA 489 NA
4.9  490 NA 490 NA
4.91 491 NA 491 NA
```

---

To get the `rownames` instead, just change your "Z" as follows:

```
Z <- apply(Slopes, 2, function(x) rownames(Slopes)[which(x>-1)])
```

Comment: Thanks, this code worked.  However, now that I see the output, it looks like my original apply code for this could have been better since it returned the row number. What I actually need is the row name. Any suggestions for changing the original apply code to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Z <- apply(Slopes, 2, function(x) which(x>-1))

str(Z)

# Length of longest sub-list
max(rapply(Z, length))
## 491

matrix_Z <- sapply(Z,'[',1:491)

tail(matrix_Z)
##     B1 B2  B3 B4
##4.86 486 NA 486 NA
##4.87 487 NA 487 NA
##4.88 488 NA 488 NA
##4.89 489 NA 489 NA
##4.9  490 NA 490 NA
##4.91 491 NA 491 NA
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that my original data frame has over 500 columns (I simplified it in order to post my problem).  Is there a good way to determine the length of the list without looking at the output for each vector by hand?